# cshell alias: How to use nested single quotes(') in in cshell alias

Tags: grep, regular-expression, quoting, alias, csh

I am trying below alias in cshell:

```
alias sll 'ls -l \!* | grep -oE '[^ ]+$' | paste -s | xargs ls -l'
```

For this CSH says, Illegal variable name.

If I use `\$`, alias will be set without any error. But when I use this alias, I get, `grep: Invalid regular expression`

PS:

1. The aim of this alias is to achieve `ls -Ll <filenames>` but with
   full path of  the file the symbolic link  references.
2. The RHS part of alias works fine as standalone command.
3. Instead of egrep (grep -E), I tried `awk '{print $NF}'`. Even for
   this, CSH gives the error: NF undefined variable.

Comment: Does csh allow nested single quotes? I suspect not. Try changing the inner single quotes to doubles.

Comment: Then the grep will try to interpret $ as a variable and hence fails.

Comment: Does csh really do that? man...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your single quotes. Single quotes don't magically nest.

```
alias sll 'ls -l \!* | grep -oE '\''[^ ]+$'\'' | xargs ls -ld --'
```

That's still flawed for several reasons:

- Because of `[^ ]`, that won't work for file or link target names that contain spaces.
- as you're treating that list as a list of lines, that won't work with file/link target names that contain newline characters.
- because of `xargs`, that won't work with file/target names containing apostrophes, backslashes, double quotes, other types of blanks.
- For symlinks with *relative* paths as their targets, that only works for symlinks in the current directory as what you pass to the second `ls` is a relative path to the current directory, while symlinks are resolved relative to the path of the symlink file (if you have a `a/b/c -> d` link, that's to `a/b/d`, not `d` in the current directory).
- you'll get a spurious error message because of the first `total <n>` line of the output of `ls`.
- for symlinks to symlinks, that won't give you the same as `ls -lL` (may be what you want though).

With `zsh`, you could make it:

```
ls -ld -- *(:A)
```

The `:A` modifier expands symlinks to their canonical absolute path.

A quasi-equivalent on GNU systems:

```
readlink -fz -- * | xargs -r0 ls -ld --
```

Comment: Thanks Stéphane Chazelas for detailed answer. It works.


With regards to flaws you mentioned, for my use case(s)

  >> Flaws 1,2,3 & 6 are not applicable.
  >> For flaw 5, i intend to either live with it or use `sll *`
  >> For flaw 4, this very much applies to my use case. I guess, I can't do it in a one liner and I have to write a script for that.